# About $f(x) = \sum_{x_n < x} c_n$ in Remark 4.31 on p.97 in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3rd Edition" by Walter Rudin.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

I am reading "Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3rd Edition" by Walter Rudin.

In Remark 4.31 on p.97, Rudin wrote this symbol $$\sum_{x_n < x} c_n.$$

What is the definition of this symbol rigorously?

I guess this symbol is equivalent to $$\sum_{n \in \{i | x_i < x\}} c_n.$$

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

In general, what is the definition of the following symbol? :
$$\sum_{n \in S} a_n.$$

If $S$ is finite, then the definition of $$\sum_{n \in S} a_n$$ is clear.

So let's consider the case in which $S$ is infinite.

Since $S$ is countable, there is a bijection $\phi : \mathbb{N} \to S$.

Is $$\sum_{n \in S} a_n := \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} a_{\phi(i)}$$ the definition of $\sum_{n \in S} a_n$?

Comment: Your interpretation is right

Comment: @YuiToCheng Thank you very much.

Comment: it should be noted that the sum is possibly dependent on the choice of bijection if the $a_i$'s are not all non-negative

Comment: @mathworker21 In that case, I would write $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ to specify that bijection.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you very much.